# Dapper.net: How to print query with parameter values

Tags: orm, dapper

Lets take an example:

```
const string PERSON_SQL = "SELECT Id " +
                           "FROM Persons " +
                           "WHERE LastName=@LastName AND FirstName=@FirstName";
patientId = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>(PERSON_SQL, new
{
    LastName = _entity.Lastname,
    FirstName = _entity.Firstname
});
```

I would like to print out actual SQL query with parameter values for debugging purposes. I am sure there is some extension or helper function for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper doesn't include that functionality itself, the authors tend to use [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) for capturing SQL queries (see [Marc Gravell's answer about something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18531238/3813189)).

You could also use SQL Profiler, presuming you're using a SQL database.

Finally, if nothing "off the shelf" suits your needs, you could wrap the database connections and commands that you use with Dapper and capture / log the queries (and parameters) when ExecuteReader, ExecuteScalar, etc.. are called. I had some sample code for this in [my answer to a question someone had about using Dapper with Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39292205/3813189) (though the sample code is database-agnostic, so you could use the "WrappedDbConnection" with whatever database you are using at the moment).

Comment: The SQL Profiler needs special permission TRACE to work. Is the same case with MiniProfiler?

Comment: The MiniProfiler examples are for a web app. Is there a C#/WPF MiniProfiler package? I guess using a wrapped DB connection would be the most suitable if there is not much code to rewrite. Otherwise a SQL profiler should be used.

Comment: There is a [MiniProfiler.Windows](https://github.com/nootn/MiniProfiler.Windows/) to answer to one of my own question, but it has not been updated for the last 4 years. (Although a pull request for update has been lately done.)